# Как правильно хранить относительно статические данные?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, архитектура, хранение-данных

Привет, интересует следующий вопрос: как правильней всего хранить относительно статические данные - в базе или в коде, или может совместить?

К примеру имеем список стран, они не меняются каждый день и с одной стороны их можно не пихать в базу данных а хранить как некий массив, пронумеровать вручную или даже использовать 2х символьные коды страны.

Потом усложним, у нас теперь есть инфа от гугловского геокодера, мы имеем place_id и крайние точки страны (bounds), это тоже как-бы неименяемые данные, но их уже похоже надо хранить в бд вместе со всем остальным что относится к странам.

Еще немного усложним, теперь нам надо развернуть приложение на другой машине, допустим список стран у нас есть, но инфы от гугла то нет, а делать 200+ запросов как некая часть миграции - тоже не вариант..

И таких примеров может быть много, одни сложнее, другие проще - валюты, языки, разные типы и виды чего-то.

Хотелось бы услышать какие-то Ваши подходы, размышления, best practices. Спасибо!

Comment: При разворачивании приложения предполагается и создание БД. Включите в дамп БД для развертывания постоянные справочники вместе с данными. Ну а где вообще хранить, конечно от приложения зависит. В БД данные нужны, как только захотите сделать join, что бы получить названия стран у городов. не сопоставлять же потом в коде выбирая из каких то массивов

Answer (score 2):

Лучше в базе. Захотите добавить что-то, поменять, добавить перевод, дополнительные индексы и т.д. Вообще хранение данных в коде - это не очень хороший стиль программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Хранит в БД для удобства, но жестко и надолго кешировать (например memcached)